# How to remove or disable non-existing playback device?

Tags: arch-linux, alsa, pulseaudio

I have this non-existing playback device. See the highlighted one on screenshots.

[image: kde pulseaudio thingy]
[image: pavucontrol]

It makes things worse, because multimedia keys on my keyboard control the volume of that device instead of the real one. I don't have anything connected via HDMI. I use a headset for sound. The existence of this device might be the reason why flash player does not produce any sound sometimes.

I am using arch linux now. I used not to have this device in other distros, and I used not to have any problems with sound in flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the first HDA device, add the line

```
options snd-hda-intel enable=0,1
```

to some .conf file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`.
Then reload the driver, or reboot.

Comment: `options snd-hda-intel enable=1,0` did it for me. Thank you.

Comment: After long search, this did the trick !!! Thanks !